# Short-circuit a UNION query when first result found

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have built a very basic UNION query in order to determine the 'type' of a UUID passed into my query like so:

```
(
  SELECT
  CASE WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN 'player_id' ELSE '' END AS uuid_type 
  FROM db.players
  WHERE id = $1
)
UNION
(
  SELECT
  CASE WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN 'game_id' ELSE '' END AS uuid_type 
  FROM db.games
  WHERE id = $1
)
UNION
(
  SELECT
  CASE WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN 'location_id' ELSE '' END AS uuid_type 
  FROM db.locations
  WHERE id = $1
)
UNION
(
  SELECT
  CASE WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN 'promo_id' ELSE '' END AS uuid_type 
  FROM db.promos
  WHERE id = $1
)
```

Is there a way to 'short-circuit' this query so that it stops when a result is found. For example, if the first sub-query succeeds and `uuid_type` is set to `player_id` I would like the query to stop, as checking the other three tables is now unnecessary.

Comment: i think you can use one `case` expression to do this.

Comment: In my experience, it's better for identifiers to include a namespace; for example, you might have `player:c495a50a-b74c-11e6-80f5-76304dec7eb7` instead of just `c495a50a-b74c-11e6-80f5-76304dec7eb7`. We often think of namespaces as just a way to prevent namespace collisions (which you're already preventing by using UUIDs), but in practice I've found that it's often very helpful for engineers (devs, QA, support, etc.) to be able to identify the type of an identifier just by looking at it, when debugging, examining logs, investigating issues, etc. *[continued]*

Comment: *[continued]* This also makes your life easier when you want to add a datatype that is mastered in a different system; for example, you might want billing to be handled by a separate microservice than the one that handles gameplay, in which case you want to know which microservice to call in order to look up a given identifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about a coalesce?

```
Select coalesce((Select 'player_id' from db.players where id = $1), 
                (Select 'game_id' from db.players where id = $1), 
                (Select 'location_id' from db.players where id = $1), 
                (Select 'promo_id' from db.players where id = $1))
```

Comment: I think this will work.  `coalesce()` is equivalent to a `case` which does do short-circuiting.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have Postgres available to test it. But it should work like this:

```
SELECT t.uuid_type
FROM (
    (
      SELECT
      CASE WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN 'player_id' ELSE '' END AS uuid_type 
      FROM db.players
      WHERE id = $1
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
      SELECT
      CASE WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN 'game_id' ELSE '' END AS uuid_type 
      FROM db.games
      WHERE id = $1
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
      SELECT
      CASE WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN 'location_id' ELSE '' END AS uuid_type 
      FROM db.locations
      WHERE id = $1
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
      SELECT
      CASE WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN 'promo_id' ELSE '' END AS uuid_type 
      FROM db.promos
      WHERE id = $1
    )
) t LIMIT 1;
```

`LIMIT 1` limits the result to a single row. And by replacing `UNION` with `UNION ALL`, the query should be more efficient as well as it doesn't need to identify and remove duplicates anymore.

Comment: This really doesn't short circuit the union, all 4 queries still run.  Additionally Limit w/o order by? are we sure the union results would always come back in the order of execution?

Comment: @xQbert: How do you know all four subqueries are executed. Do you have an execution statistics that show this? The LIMIT statement is a strong hint for the optimizer not to fetch data eagerly. And my assumption is that the `id` columns are disjunct across the four tables. Otherwise the query doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Codo: It will short-circuit a `UNION ALL`, though not a `UNION` (which will run all subqueries and filter out duplicates before applying the limit). Here's a [demo](http://rextester.com/DXSG68122); as you can see, the second query's `Seq scan on b` node says "never executed".

Comment: @NickBarnes: Sorry. I wrote that I replaced `UNION` with `UNION ALL` when in fact I didn't. I've fixed this now.